# Earth Engine Image Zone Statistics (zonal stats)

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics

I am looking at object oriented methods and wondered if there was a way of calculating image zone statistics (zonal stats) based on connected pixels. Essentially, I want to reduce the pixels in an independent image (eg. Sentinel-1) by the image object in a connected pixels image.

For example, I have a binary image (1m res) that I turn into objects using connected pixels and remove objects below 100 pixels:

```
// Convert to objects
var patchsize = InFile.connectedPixelCount(256,false).reproject({crs:'EPSG:4326',scale:1})
Map.addLayer(patchsize, {}, 'patch size');

// Remove small objects
var PatchMask = patchsize.gt(100)
Map.addLayer(PatchMask, {}, 'patch mask');

var FinalSegs = InFile.updateMask(PatchMask)
```

I also create monthly mean Sentinel-1 images using the following code:

```
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD");

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function (m) {
    return sentinel1
    // Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
   // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  //clip to bangladesh
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                .select('VH')
                .mean()
                .set('month', m);
}));
print(byMonth);
```

I would ideally like to reduce the pixels in the Sentinel-1 images (12 mean images) using the objects the connected pixels. I presume the output would be a 12 band image where each object has the mean backscatter value for each connected pixel. Is this possible in EE?

A badly drawn example of this would like the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273658/performing-object-based-image-classification-in-google-earth-engine), which uses a recent script by Noel Gorelick.

The lines of code required to do what I want are:

```
img = byMonth.mean()

var MeanImage = img.addBands(FinalSegs).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.mean(), 'segs', 256)
```