# SNIC (Simple Non-Iterative Clustering) using Python - Google Colab

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, google-colab

I am trying to use SNIC (Simple Non-Iterative Clustering) for clustering land cover areas using python - Google Earth Engine. I am following [OBIA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273658/performing-object-based-image-classification-in-google-earth-engine) as a guide. However, I am getting this error:

```
EEException: Unrecognized argument type to convert to an Image: {'image': <ee.image.Image object at 0x7f662b6e48b0>, 'size': 32, 'compactness': 5, 'connectivity': 8, 'neighborhoodSize': 256, 'seeds': <ee.image.Image object at 0x7f662b4b1130>}
```

Code:

```
countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017") 
canada = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq("country_na", "Canada"))
img = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")\
              .filterDate('01-01-2020','31-12-2020')\
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))\
              .filterBounds(canada)\
              .median()\
              .clip(canada)
seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(36)
snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
'image': img, 
'size': 32,
'compactness': 5,
'connectivity': 8,
'neighborhoodSize':256,
'seeds': seeds
 })
Map.addLayer(snic.select('clusters').randomVisualizer(),{}, 'NDVI')
Map
```

Why is this error popping up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python functions don't take dictionary-based arguments.
Use "=" or dereference the dictionary:

```
snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC(
  image=img, 
  size=32,
  compactness=5,
  connectivity=8,
  neighborhoodSize=256,
  seeds=seeds)
```